# Push some files - Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I used SVN that I could commit some file on repository and now I want to use GIT that I can't use push for some files! please help me what I do? I heard about create new branch and push this but I need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To push an updated file to remote repo you do:

```
git checkout master
//update file
git add <file>
git commit -m "my first commit"
git push origin master
```

If you want another branch than master, create it like this (the new branch will be tracking master):

```
git checkout -b my_branch origin/master
git push origin
```

Comment: 'git push origin master' pushed all files. I want push some files!

Comment: No it pushed the commit you have created, and before creating the commit you use `git add` to select the files you want to include.

Comment: Oops! I got it! tnQ